# ¿Como solucionar el problema de guardar un registro en BD android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Que tal amigos estoy creando un registro de usuarios de una app en android studio y guardarlos en la base de datos con el gestor MySQL , el cual he venido teniendo un problemas con el servidor local lo tengo con xampp,cuando lleno el registro y doy clic en el botón registrar no sucede nada ni tampoco me manda un error en el `Logcat`, por ahí leí información que cuando digite el `ip` de mi red local después agregue el puerto de mi servidor pero aun así lo intente y no me funciono.

**PHP**

```
<?php 

 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","logishuman","root","");

 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $nombreUsuario = $_POST["nombreUsuario"];
 $email = $_POST["email"];
 $contraseña = $_POST["contraseña"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO    t_usuario_final(nombre,nombreUsuario,email,contraseña) VALUES 
 (?,?,?,?)");

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $nombre, $nombreUsuario, $email, $contraseña);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response ["success"] = true;
echo json_encode($response);

 ?>
```

**RegistroUser.java**

```
public class RegistroUser extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro_user);
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Formulario de registro");

 EditText nombreT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texnombre);
 EditText nombreUsuarioT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texnombreuser);
 EditText emailT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texcorreo);
 EditText contraseñaT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texpass);
 Button btnregistrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnregistrar);

 btnregistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         String nombre = nombreT.getText().toString();
         String nombreUsuario = nombreUsuarioT.getText().toString();
         String email = emailT.getText().toString();
         String contraseña = contraseñaT.getText().toString();

         Response.Listener<String> respuesta = new Response.Listener<String>() {
             @Override
             public void onResponse(String response) {

                 try {
                     JSONObject jsonRespuesta = new JSONObject(response);
                     boolean ok = jsonRespuesta.getBoolean("success");
                     if (ok == true) {
                         Intent i = new Intent(RegistroUser.this, LoginActivity.class);
                         RegistroUser.this.startActivity(i);
                         RegistroUser.this.finish();
                     } else {
                         AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegistroUser.this);
                         alerta.setMessage("El registro a fallado").setNegativeButton("Reintentar de nuevo", null)
                                 .create()
                                 .show();
                     }
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.getMessage();
                 }
             }
         };
         RegistroRequest r = new RegistroRequest(nombre, nombreUsuario, email, contraseña,  respuesta);
         RequestQueue cola = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegistroUser.this);
         cola.add(r);
     }
 });

  }
 }
```

**RegistroRequest.java**

```
public class RegistroRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String ruta = "http://192.168.5.12/LogisticaHumanitaria/registroUserFinal.php";
private Map<String, String> parametros;
public RegistroRequest(String nombre,String nombreUsuario,String email, String contraseña,   Response.Listener<String> listener){
super(Request.Method.POST, ruta, listener,   null);
parametros = new HashMap<>();
parametros.put("nombre",nombre+"");
parametros.put("nombreUsuario",nombreUsuario+"");
parametros.put("email",email+"");
parametros.put("contraseña",contraseña+"");
 }

 @Override
  protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
  return parametros;
  }
}
```

**build.gradle**
Tengo agregado la siguiente libreria

`implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'`

**AndroidManifest.xml** tengo agregado lo siguiente

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

Comment: ¿Dónde está el `onError` de tu petición Volley? Pon un `Log.d` también en el `onResponse`  y así vas siguiendo el código y nos dices: la petición ocurre, entra en tal parte, o, no ocurre, entra en el onError y el motivo del error es tal... Por cierto, no es buena idea usar `ñ` o acentos para nombrar tus variables, columnas, tablas, etc. Suelen traer problemas debido a la codificación.

Comment: Prueba también si esta URL funciona, escribiéndola en el navegador: `http://192.168.5.12/LogisticaHumanitaria/registroUserFinal.php`

Comment: @A.Cedano la URL si funciona colocando el IP, pero no se is tenga que ver ya que estoy desde una PC y en lugar del emulador estoy usando mi celular.